# apps removed are still creating folders in android

Tags: delete

Folders/files which are deleted are being re-created on my SD card.
Not sure which app is re-creating it(or is it Android which is recreating, how can I confirm which app)

I delete them, but these come back after sometime 
/storage/sdcard0/Movies/PicassoLib/
/storage/sdcard0/Music/PicassoLib/
/storage/sdcard0/z7logs/many.zip files
about phone screenshot is attached.

Any help to make sure its not created again will be helpful.
[image]

Comment: You're going to have to give more details to get any help. What apps? What folders are being created? What phone do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Your files that keep reappearing are due to the fact that they still have the apps installed that  are associated with them.

---

The first 2 folders are from Picasso - which is an image download service, and does more than just that. Its a very important part of the Android OS. Without this and things don't work right, unless you find a replacement that will integrate with the system. Volley and Universal Image Loader are the other 2 contenders that come to mind. Getting rid of those folders isn't an option for you.

The last one, /7zlogs, is associated with a compress/decompress app. It is a folder that hold the log files from the app. You should be able to go into the apps settings and turn off logging. Once done with that you can delete the folder without the chance of it reappearing.

*Be careful of what you delete, ALWAYS do a backup before messing with anything*

Comment: HasH_BrowN,
thanks for replying.. > they still have the apps associated with them -I checked and Android is 101% sure that these 2 apps are not installed anymore. -I checked 'my apps' under google play store, which lists all apps, even the ones that were uninstalled(these 2 have X with it which indicates its not installed). -Hence I guess 'apps removed are still creating folders', please let me know how to remove completely(manually), so that these folders are not created automatically anymore.

Comment: @user72121 read my answer again i edited it.